# How to make responsive background-image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I made such background for my `div`

[image]

But when I make screen-size smaller, then you can see white space here:

[image]

So how I can fixed this?

```
        <div className="bg-home-page">

            <div className="box-discount">
               //some code
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.bg-home-page
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: flex-end
    background-image: url('../../assets/bg1.jpg')
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: center center
    background-size: 100%
    min-height: 550px
```

Comment: You can align the background to the top with background-position: top center or use background-size: cover to fully cover the div.

Comment: @KeesHak when i use  **background-position: top center** it makes **div** with height like **100vh** (it cover all screen).. and when i use **background-size: cover** - it cut my background

Comment: That is because you use min-height. Another suggestion is not to use min-height and not use the image as a background-image but simply use the HTML img element with a display: block and width: 100%.

Comment: Get rid of those other background properties, then: `background:center / contain no-repeat url('../../assets/bg1.jpg');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a this situation, Never use `min-height` because it makes the quality of image decrease's. Probably your parent can't control the child. your background-image should be `top center` and `background-size: contain;`
if it doesn't work make a jsfiddle or codepen with your codes i can fix it quickly but your snippet its hard to figure out i need your parents styles too.
look at these demos (they can help you) :
https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/responsive-background-image/

Comment: Thank you, It's almost i need!